# Store codeigniter shopping cart

Tags: php, mysql, session, codeigniter

Ive already finish creating the shopping cart in codeigniter using shopping cart class. but the data was stored in session in array then i want to store the session array in database user_ordered. with userid, productid, qty. or other values.

Comment: I can't really tell what you are asking here... Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Did you try anything yet, like reading `$this->cart->contents()`? Can you put this in the form of a question and explain the actual problem, what you're trying to do exactly, what ideas and/or code you've tried if any?... Is this supposed to happen every time an item is added or on checkout only?

Comment: when the user is going to checkout i want to save in database.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily store your Session Array in the database using codeIgniter. In order to store sessions, you must first create a database table for this purpose. Here is the basic prototype (for MySQL) required by the session class:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

By default the table is called `ci_sessions`, but you can name it anything you want as long as you update the `application/config/config.php` file so that it contains the name you have chosen. Once you have created your database table you can enable the database option in your `config.php` file as follows:

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

Once enabled, the Session class will store session data in the DB.

Make sure you've specified the table name in your config file as well:

```
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

The same instructions can be found in the [codeigniter documentation.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)